# Ayuda Con base de datos en Angular 4

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, angular

Estoy desarrollando una web app en angular, ya hice el ApiRest y la probé con Postman y bueno en teoría (no estoy seguro) todo el código en angular esta bien ya que no me tira ningún error, pero los datos que agrego desde el formulario no se guardan en la base de datos, me refiero a que en la base aparece un nuevo producto pero vació, por otro lado cuando agrego productos desde Postman si se guarda todo correctamente.

Este es el codigo de los servicios.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/observable';
import { Producto } from '../models/producto';
import { GLOBAL } from './global';

@Injectable()
export class ProductoService{
    public url: string;

    constructor(
        public _http : Http

    ){
        this.url=GLOBAL.url;
    }
    getProductos(){
        return this._http.get(this.url+'productos').map(res => res.json());
    }

    addProducto(producto: Producto){
        let json = JSON.stringify(producto);
        let params = 'json='+json;
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

        return this._http.post(this.url+'productos',params,{headers:headers})
                         .map(res => res.json());

    }
}
```

El codigo del componente para agregar elementos a la base de datos

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import { ProductoService } from '../services/producto.service';
import { Producto } from '../models/producto';

@Component({
    selector: 'producto-add',
    templateUrl: '../views/producto-add.html',
    providers: [ProductoService]
})

export class ProdcutoAddComponent{
    public titulo: string;
    public producto: Producto;

    constructor(
        private _productoService:ProductoService,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute,
        private _router: Router
    ){
        this.titulo = 'Crear un nuevo producto';
        this.producto = new Producto(0,'','',0,'');
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        console.log('El componente de agregar un producto se ha cargado correctamente');
    }
    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.producto);
        this._productoService.addProducto(this.producto).subscribe(
            response =>{
                if(response.code == 200){
                    this._router.navigate(['/productos-list']);
                }else{
                    console.log(response);
                }

            },
            error =>{
                console.log(<any> error);

            }

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: No veo donde tienes el formulario, por lo que se ve solo introduce en la base el this.producto = new Producto(0,'','',0,''), que has inicializado.
Estas utilizando Reactive Forms? Si puedes poner el html quizás puedo ayudarte más. Saludos

Comment: Es extraño pero volví a escribir el código de servicios y funcionó aunque tuve problemas para subir archivos pero ya lo solucione mmmm en realidad no se que estuvo mal muchas gracias